# Sensitive data exposure in Burp

Tags: security, testing, penetration-testing, burp

I have very little knowledge about security testing. I have been given a assignment to do penetration testing using burp free version.

When I started using burp suite then on a page of employee information I saw requests are passing as plain text. Can we consider it as sensitive data exposure ?

Can anyone give me details how hacker can use such information?  [Click here for Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scYWt.png)

Comment: Is this a training assignment? If you have “very little knowledge about security testing”, maybe someone else should do security testing…?

Comment: You can't conclude that. Burp is an SSL-breaking proxy so it able to view plain text even when the communication is encrypted. In Proxy > HTTP History, look at the SSL column. If this is not ticked, then the message is unencrypted.

Comment: It is not ticketed. Means message is encrypted which means its vulnerable.

Comment: Yes, the snapshot which you provided shows that it's vulnerable.